# Face ID with Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, face-recognition

I would like to know if you know how I can create a database of faces that is fed with a mobile application made with flutter, I have knowledge in flutter but I have never done facial recognition, so I have the doubt that if it is possible to create a flutter application in which the user has to register using his face and when he wants to enter the app he has to show his face to the camera and so the application check if that face exists in the database

Answer (score 0):

As I know, flutter app only can using face detection with this [firebase_ml_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision) package. It can't or maybe it's not support recognize face yet.

If you want to do that, you can use face detection with flutter app to detect face then send that face with a Google service to recognize it and receive the result to do what you want.